# SUM sequential groups of 12 cells from a variable column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying calculate maintenance spend based on when an asset was purchased, in each year of it's life, however, there are some anomalies that are causing me issues:

- each asset was brought in a different month / year
- some assets were purchased before maintenance costs were kept on record
- Format of data is less than ideal

This Link is to a question that proved very helpful but couldn't get it to work with the above anomalies: [SUM sequential groups of 12 cells from a row in another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723036/sum-sequential-groups-of-12-cells-from-a-row-in-another-worksheet)

Example of worksheet:
[image: Example of worksheet]

Comment: I find it odd that you refuse to show what formula you tried let alone describe why it is not returning the results you expect.

Comment: Sorry - this is my first time at asking a question - I knew I'd forget something....the formula I used is it seems to work for the changing columns, but not for dates starting in previous years which I think is something to do with leap years, but not sure..... also it's very complicated and thought there might be an easier way? =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(($B7+3+((JW$2-1)*366))-DAY(($B7+2+((JW$2-1)*366))),$1:$1),"ERROR")="ERROR",0,SUM(INDEX($D7:$JV7,1,(1+((JW$2-1-COUNTIF($JV7:JV7,0))*12)+MATCH($B7,$1:$1)-5)):INDEX($D7:$JV7,1,13+((JW$2-1-COUNTIF($JV7:JV7,0))*12)+(MATCH($B7,$1:$1)-6))))

Comment: in the above formula, JW$2 refers to the year number